# How to set height by screen-height, not by browser-height

Tags: css, position, height

How do I set the height of a div container for example that should be 60% of the screen height?
Setting the 60% as the height in css works fine if the browser window is not resized. But if I shrink the browser window, the div shrinks accordingly.
https://zurb.com provides a nice example. The "Mission Accomplished", grey part is always the same height, no matter how the browser window is being resized. How can this be ensured?
I don't want to use px to ensure HiDpi support.

Thanks,

Comment: You'd have to use JS APIs to get the screen height, then multiple it by your percentage.

Comment: So you're wanting to basically save the screen height when the page is first rendered, and then keep those exact dimensions regardless of changes to the browser size? Yeah, that'll require JS.

Comment: That website is just a fixed height and has nothing to do with screen height.

Comment: "I don't want to use px to ensure HiDpi support." `px` works fine regardless of DPI (it uses logical pixels).  You shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks, I was guessing so but didn't know that the logical pixels work this fine also in big resolution differences! This helped me,

Answer (score 0):

While the page in question simply used a **fixed** height (`px`) for the element in question, meaning that it will always have the same height (and won't be `60%` of the height regardless of viewport height). In order to have an element be relative to the viewport, you're looking for **[viewport-sized typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)**.

To adjust based on height, you're looking for the CSS unit `vh`, which tells the element in question to scale based on the viewport height. You can also use `vw` to scale based on the viewport width.

Keep in mind that `<body>` has a default of `margin: 8px`, so if you want to avoid scrollbars when using viewport-sized typography, you'll also need to override this back to `0`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

For more in-depth information on CSS units, I'd recommend checking out **[this guide](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/understanding-css-units/)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this isn't what I intended. When you runthe snippet in fullscreen and resize the window, your red box will resize too.

Comment: Viewport isn't screen.

Comment: @j.Doe: Yes; you just want a fixed height in `px`.

Comment: The viewport `<meta>` elimites DPI issues, and you said you wanted the element to be 60% of the height of the height of the screen, which requires viewport-sized typography. Using a fixed height (`px`) will make it the same height **regardless** of screen size (meaning it won't always be `60%`).

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple fixed-height element; it has nothing to do with screen size.

You should just use `px` and not worry about anything; `px` means logical pixels and will work with arbitrary DPIs.

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't know that the px work this fine with arbitrary DPIs.